# timeout [error]configuration not set properly . missing value for session

Tags: java, playframework-2.3

I have a `Play Java` application and have to integrate `deadbolt2` and `google juice`. When I try to run my application my cmd shows me this error.

```
timeout [error]configuration not set properly . missing value for session.
```

I think the problem is somewhere in the global class. But I haven't been able to find a solution to this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Would you share your `application.conf` and `Global.java`, please?

Comment: Im sorry I am not allowed to share any code.i know its a fuss but if you could redirect me to an example on similar lines, it might just do it for me.

Comment: Which version of Deadbolt are you using?  2.3.3 no longer has explicit timeouts.   On the other hand, this doesn't look like anything Deadbolt would complain about.

Comment: I'm using deadbolt 2.3.2

Comment: Is there a stack trace associated with this?

Comment: I got through with this issue but now i am getting a subject not present issue.I saw this -the trick is to store the user in the context, and then have your controller or deadbolt handler to access it. This allows you to store the user by the actual class, and not have to use getSubject() and cast the resulting Subject to your actual User class.
    But i dont know how to go about it .Could you please help me out.I cannot make any changes to HttpContext .